# Field validation error in sorting expression

Tags: validation, reporting-services, field

I have a problem with the sorting formula in my tablix. The sorting was always as follows:

```
cint(Fields!KeyForRows.Value)
```

But now the fields can contain alphanumeric values. So i tried to change it to:

```
iif(Parameters!DrillMain.Value ="...", Fields!KeyForRows.Value, cint(Fields!KeyForRows.Value))
```

But this doesn't work. As far as I understand, this is because my case sorting is 
`Fields!KeyForRows.Value`, it checks the other part of condition and fails on validation,  and I need to preserve sorting as integer.

Comment: Can you give an example of what a dataset might look like, specifically showing the different types of *KeyForRows* values you might get?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct with iif logic - it's calculate both statements. As a workaround you can define your custom IIF or write your expression as follow:

```
IIF(Parameters!DrillMain.Value ="...", Fields!KeyForRows.Value, 
          cint(IIF(Parameters!DrillMain.Value ="...", Nothing, Fields!KeyForRows.Value)))
```

Thanks for second nested iif you'll never pass invalid data into CInt function. If KeyForRows is alphabetic then into CInt you pass Nothing instead of KeyForRows  value.

Comment: +1 I agree but I'd suggest you use `isnumeric()` in the second `iif`